# Cannot convert Multipage Tiff image into text using tesseract

Tags: text, ocr, tesseract, tiff, multipage

I am trying to convert multipage tiff file into text but it is not converting it into text. It gives this error. Can anyone resolve the issue and guide me what I am doing wrong.

```
C:\Users\raintree\Desktop\Sample_Files>tesseract output.tif outputmulitiff

Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.00dev with Leptonica

Error in pixReadFromTiffStream: spp not in set {1,3,4}
```